# Configure PTP_Timescale parameter

Tags: ptp

I am using ptp4l on linux machine.
Currently, in the pcap trace I can see that the flag for PTP_Timescale is set to False.
Is there anyway, that I can configure the PTP_Timescale parameter and set it to True?

Answer (score 0):

The `pmc` tool may be the answer you are looking for (I think the `pmc` tool is included in the [linuxptp package](https://command-not-found.com/pmc)).

**First Step:**

Let's try and read your current configuration using the `pmc` tool:

```
sudo pmc -u -b 0 'GET GRANDMASTER_SETTINGS_NP'
```

You should get a response in this structure:

```
sending: GET GRANDMASTER_SETTINGS_NP                                           
        020e06.fffe.814208-0 seq 0 RESPONSE MANAGEMENT GRANDMASTER_SETTINGS_NP 
                clockClass              255                                    
                clockAccuracy           0x21                                   
                offsetScaledLogVariance 0x436a                                 
                currentUtcOffset        37                                     
                leap61                  0                                      
                leap59                  0                                      
                currentUtcOffsetValid   1                                      
                ptpTimescale            0                                      
                timeTraceable           0                                      
                frequencyTraceable      0                                      
                timeSource              0xa0
```

**Second Step:**

Let's modify the `timeTraceable` flag to 1 using a `pmc` command (please note that I'm not changing the other flags - I'm writing the same values I've just read, except the `timeTraceable` that we want to change):

```
sudo pmc -u -b 0 "SET GRANDMASTER_SETTINGS_NP clockClass 255 \
            clockAccuracy 0x21 offsetScaledLogVariance 0x436a \
            currentUtcOffset 37 leap61 0 leap59 0 currentUtcOffsetValid 1 \
            ptpTimescale 1 timeTraceable 0 frequencyTraceable 0 \
            timeSource 0xa0"
```

I hope this will do the job. If it doesn't help, try have a look at this links for more details:
[pmc man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/pmc.8.html)
[pmc example](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/6/html/deployment_guide/s1-using_the_ptp_management_client)

Comment: I already tried to set the timesclace using pmc. But, in the trace I see that the ptp_timescale is still 0 (though I updated the Grandmaster settings using pmc).

Comment: Did you try the exact command I've posted here ? I tried it on one of my slaves/clients and the flag did changed his value. (note that when I tried the command with "pmc -t...." it didn't work, so I removed the "-t". don't know why it didn't work that way)

Comment: When you type again: sudo pmc -u -b 0 'GET GRANDMASTER_SETTINGS_NP' , the "timeTraceable" is still set to '0' ?

Comment: When try 'GET GRANDMASTER_SETTINGS_NP', the ptp_timescale is set to 1. But, in the wireshark trace i see that the ptp_timescale is still 0.